# Sorting table with variables not sorting right

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a table whose data is fetched from the database.  So the code for a single cell looks like this:

```
 <td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>" . $row["charts_retrace"]. "</td>
```

I have 8 columns in the table.  Most of the columns contain numbers, one column has letters (eg: EG, TR, CD, HJ), and another column has dates (eg: september 14, 2015).  What I want to do is sort them so that are numbers go from low to high and vice versa, the dates go from the past to present and visa versa, and the letters in order alphabetically.

i got my javascript to work but the sorting is wrong.  Any idea on what the right code should be or what code I can use for sorting?

The javascript I am using is from this site: http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/

Snippets of what my code looks like:

The table in my PHP code:

```
 <table id='my_table' style='border: solid #000000 1px;border-collapse:collapse;'>
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>Chart</u></strong></td>
```

My javascript in my header file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/gs_sortable.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 var TSort_Data = new Array ('my_table', '', 'd', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 's');
 tsRegister();
 // -->
 </script>
```

**Here's my new code (from a rendered page) that uses tha tablesorter:**

The head section:

```html
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Charts (Members Only) | MLS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/themes/PersonalFinance/lib/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/themes/PersonalFinance/lib/css/defaults.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/themes/PersonalFinance/lib/css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->
<script src="http://www.mlsinc.net/sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mlsinc.net/tablesorter-master/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mlsinc.net/tablesorter-master/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} )); 
    } 
); 
</script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/themes/PersonalFinance/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
   window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"http:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/www.mlsinc.net\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.1"}};
   !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c=b.createElement("canvas"),d=c.getContext&&c.getContext("2d");return d&&d.fillText?(d.textBaseline="top",d.font="600 32px Arial","flag"===a?(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55356,56812,55356,56807),0,0),c.toDataURL().length>3e3):(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55357,56835),0,0),0!==d.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0])):!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f;c.supports={simple:d("simple"),flag:d("flag")},c.supports.simple&&c.supports.flag||(f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
 display: inline !important;
 border: none !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
 height: 1em !important;
 width: 1em !important;
 margin: 0 .07em !important;
 vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
 background: none !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='siteorigin-panels-front-css'  href='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/siteorigin-panels/css/front.css?ver=2.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-lightbox-2.min.css-css'  href='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-lightbox-2/styles/lightbox.min.css?ver=1.3.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='quick_chat_style_sheet-css'  href='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/quick-chat/css/quick-chat.css?ver=4.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='quick_chat_ie_style_sheet-css'  href='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/quick-chat/css/quick-chat-ie.css?ver=4.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ws-plugin--s2member-css'  href='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/s2member/s2member-o.php?ws_plugin__s2member_css=1&#038;qcABC=1&#038;ver=150311-3606627542' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/ckeditor/";
var ckeditorSettings = { "textarea_id": "comment", "pluginPath": "http:\/\/www.mlsinc.net\/wp-content\/plugins\/ckeditor-for-wordpress\/", "autostart": true, "excerpt_state": false, "qtransEnabled": false, "outputFormat": { "indent": true, "breakBeforeOpen": true, "breakAfterOpen": true, "breakBeforeClose": true, "breakAfterClose": true }, "configuration": { "height": "160px", "skin": "moono", "scayt_autoStartup": false, "entities": true, "entities_greek": true, "entities_latin": true, "toolbar": "WordpressBasic", "templates_files": [ "http:\/\/www.mlsinc.net\/wp-content\/plugins\/ckeditor-for-wordpress\/ckeditor.templates.js" ], "stylesCombo_stylesSet": "wordpress:http:\/\/www.mlsinc.net\/wp-content\/plugins\/ckeditor-for-wordpress\/ckeditor.styles.js", "allowedContent": true, "customConfig": "http:\/\/www.mlsinc.net\/wp-content\/plugins\/ckeditor-for-wordpress\/ckeditor.config.js" }, "externalPlugins": [  ], "additionalButtons": [  ] }
/* ]]> */
</script>  <style type="text/css">
    #content table.cke_editor { margin:0; }
    #content table.cke_editor tr td { padding:0;border:0; }
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/themes/PersonalFinance/lib/js/superfish.js?ver=4.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/themes/PersonalFinance/lib/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js?ver=4.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?t=E8PA&#038;ver=4.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/includes/ckeditor.utils.js?ver=4.2.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 

<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.mlsinc.net/charts/' />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://www.mlsinc.net/?p=35' />
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-61795914-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MLS RSS Feed" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/feed/" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.mlsinc.net/xmlrpc.php" />
 <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
 * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
 @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
  html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
  * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
 }
</style>

</head>
```

The table:

```html
<h2>Charts</h2><br><br>
   <table id='myTable' class='tablesorter' style='border: solid #000000 1px;border-collapse:collapse;'>
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>Chart</u></strong></td>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>Date</u></strong></td>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>Retrace</u></strong></td>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>Start of Swing Trade</u></strong></td>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>End of Swing Trade</u></strong></td>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>Bull flag</u></strong></td>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>Bear flag</u></strong></td>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>EMA Crossover</u></strong></td>
       <th style='border: solid #000000 1px;padding:15px;'><strong><u>Trading Instrument</u></strong></td>
     </tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/resultspage.jpg><img src=images/resultspage.jpg width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>may 15, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>ES</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/mls_paypal.gif><img src=images/mls_paypal.gif width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>jan 14, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>EQ</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/intraday-new-1-1024x479.png><img src=images/intraday-new-1-1024x479.png width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>dec 14, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>EQ</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/signature.jpg><img src=images/signature.jpg width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>dec 14, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>EQ</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/intraday-new-1-1024x479.png><img src=images/intraday-new-1-1024x479.png width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>dec 14, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>EQ</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/intraday-new-1-1024x479.png><img src=images/intraday-new-1-1024x479.png width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>may 14, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>ES</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/intraday-new-1-1024x479.png><img src=images/intraday-new-1-1024x479.png width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>may 1, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>ES</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=><img src= width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>may 1, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>ES</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=><img src= width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>may 1, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>ES</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/resultspage.jpg><img src=images/resultspage.jpg width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>may 15, 2015</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>232</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>322</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3434</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>ES</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/logo_large.png><img src=images/logo_large.png width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>dec 1, 2020</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>34</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>43</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>324</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>543</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>234</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>343</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>WS</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'><a href=images/next.gif><img src=images/next.gif width='200px'></a></td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>feb 6, 2089</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>34</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>34</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>43</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3423</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>4</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>3</td><td style='border: solid #000000 1px;'>ET</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: You tagged this with `php` and `mysql`. Are you doing the sorting using `ORDER BY` in the SQL query? If so, show the code that does this. If not, those tag are irrelevant.

Comment: My code is PHP but I am using SQL variables within the PHP code....does that count?

Comment: You haven't shown any of the PHP or SQL code in the question. Is it relevant to the sorting? If you're doing all the sorting in JS, probably not.

Comment: actually the HTML and PHP are combined in one file.  I just showed the HTML part of it because it is relevant to getting my question answered.  I posted the JS code that I put into the header as well as a link to where I got the JS from for reference.  so remove php and mysql and replace with html in the tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the problem lies in the third party table sorting script you are using.  It is likely that you are using it incorrectly, which could be because the script is buggy, because the documentation is wrong, or because you have misunderstood how to use it.  I have not used that script and you are unlikely to get support for a 3rd party script on SO unless it is very well known.

I had a quick look at the Table_Sort docs you linked to, and you seem to be using it in the correct way.  Double check that your column types match up with the ones you have in your array.  Since you haven't provided an example of the data you are sorting it is not clear from your question whether you are using the right parameters, nor is it clear which columns are not sorting correctly.  It is likely that your date is in an incorrect format as the script you are using does not seem to provide localisation or date formatting options, so it is probably not reading it correctly.

If you would like more help with using this script, please provide an example of the table including which columns are not behaving as they should!  If there is no particular reason to use this script, why not use a more common, tried and tested one such as Christian Bach's [TableSorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter)?  It is free and highly customisable, much easier to use, and being far more common is likely to have fewer bugs and a great deal more support.

### Edit for new TableSorter problem

I took a look at your code and the problem in your case is simply invalid HTML.  Two simple changes will get it working:

- in your table heading you have accidentally closed your `<th>` tags with `<\td>`.  Change all of these tags to `<\th>`.
- in your table body, you have placed `</tbody><tbody>` in between each row.  `<tr>...</tr>` denotes a HTML row, `<tbody>...<\tbody>` is meant to enclose all the body rows.  Performing a replace on `</tbody><tbody>` to an empty string will clear this up.

The script might have been working but only had one row to sort (the top one) so it looked like it was doing nothing!  This may have been the problem with the previous script you were using, so you can revert to using that if you prefer, but I found TableSorter to be excellent.  Hope this helps and gets you on your way!  Good luck.

Comment: funny thing is I actually decided to change scripts and the script that I found and decided to use was the one you referred me to haha!  problem is it doesn't seem to work :( my table isn't sorting and my column headers are not clickable.

Comment: Hi Thomas, having just implemented TableSorter in my own app I am sure I can help, but I need more information.  Please can you post the new JavaScript that uses TableSorter, and copy the HTML of the table from the rendered page?  (F12 dev tools).

Comment: Posted, look at my post above.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the fix - just a couple of minor HTML mistakes that prevented the script from working correctly!

Comment: awesome, it worked! can't believe i didn't see those small mistakes.   now i gotta figure out how to edit the column headers so they look like clickable links or at least inform users that they can click on them.  wish there was an up and down arrow in the code.

Comment: Great glad to help!  If my answer helped, please upvote/mark as answer, I need the points!  The column headers are styled with CSS.  Themes are provided on the site (http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/blue.zip).  It's just a case of including the theme files (the CSS and arrow images).  Shouldn't be hard but if you run into complications ask a question and I'll look out for you.